# compiling with librestc-cpp : undefined reference to pthread_condattr_setclock

Tags: c++, ld

I'm trying to use the [librestc-cpp](https://github.com/jgaa/restc-cpp), a lib that allows to create C++ API clients.
It uses Boost as a dependency.

I am *not* using CMake.

I copied the first [tutorial](https://github.com/jgaa/restc-cpp/blob/master/doc/Tutorial.md) program (the first two blocks indicated), and compiled it with a Makefile :

```
g++ -c -o src/main.o src/main.cpp
g++ -o test src/main.o -lrestc-cpp -lboost_system
```

The first command runs fine.
However I get the following error during the linkage :

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/librestc-cpp.a(RestClientImpl.cpp.o): undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_condattr_setclock@@GLIBC_2.3.3'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Using readelf I can confirm the symbol exists :

```
$ readelf -s /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 | grep pthread_condattr_setclock
   104: 0000000000010f50    28 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 pthread_condattr_setclock@@GLIBC_2.3.3
   170: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS pthread_condattr_setclock
   755: 0000000000010f50    28 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 pthread_condattr_setclock
```

I tried adding `-lpthread` to the second command, but it simply breaks everything - I get a thousand linker errors from both libs - too much to even scroll to the top of the output.

Comment: where did you get librestc-cpp.a from?

Comment: @user7860670 I built from the sources I linked in the post : https://github.com/jgaa/restc-cpp